# anyone who use vscode for python (vscode show all the code but output)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am coding python using VS code.
However, all the codes I wrote are printed out on the terminal. And then you get the printed value.
For example, When I write 1+3, I only want see 4 but the terminal show me 1+3 and 4.
I hope only the printed value come out on the terminal.
I don't know what's wrong with the setting and it's coming out like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUnTb.png)

I am coding python using VS code.
However, all the codes I wrote are printed out on the terminal. And then you get the printed value.
For example, When I write 1+3, I only want see 4 but the terminal show me 1+3 and 4.
I hope only the printed value come out on the terminal.
I don't know what's wrong with the setting and it's coming out like this.

```
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>> 1+3
4
>>> 2+8
10
>>>
```

Comment: `anyone who use vscode for python` is an understatement, 62M people have installed the Python Language extension. Hopefully at least 2 use it (Me and some other of the 62M)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your picture, you're entering '1+3' into the terminal, correct? That's why you're seeing 1+3 followed by 4. The 1+3 in the terminal (as well as the 'print("Hello")') are what you've typed in. If you only want to see the output of your code in the terminal, you need to run the python script directly using the 'python3' command.

In your chapter1 > testt.py file, you have:

```
print("Hello") 
1+3
2+8
```

Try updating this to look like:

```
print("Hello")
print(1+3)
print(2+8)
```

and save your file.

Then, in the terminal, type:

```
python3 testt.py
```

This command actually runs the script. Then you'll see the output from the scrip (the print statements), and you should see:

```
Hello
4
10
```

The distinction between the terminal and what it displays and the actual results of your code can be confusing when first starting programming. Good luck!

Comment: This is helpful! I liked that you showed all the steps.